# How to make a section take entire space in Dynamics CRM form editor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

Inside our Microsoft Dynamics CRM instance, we've got a section which is taking 1/3<sup>rd</sup> of the space inside the form editor:

[image: Dynamics CRM form editor section]

After saving and publishsing this, it takes 1/3<sup>rd</sup> of the space on the rendering output along with [trolls of scrolls](http://usabilitygeek.com/horizontal-scrolling-user-experience-best-practices/):

[image: Dynamics CRM form section]

> How to make a section take entire space in Dynamics CRM form editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the form editor, select the Tab (not the section), and click "Change properties".

[image: Change Properties]

Then in the formatting tab, select "One column", and finish with OK.

[image: Tab formatting]

Finally, save and publish your form and it should fill the entire space.